# Is it possible to read data directly from a database table for batch processing in Apache Flink than reading from a csv file?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, dataset, apache-flink, batch-processing

I need my Flink batch job to read data from my Spring Boot project's postgres database. The option I saw in Flink is only for reading from csv files. In that case I need to create a csv file from my table. Is there any solution out there?

Comment: YES! that is exactly why databases exist. NowI do not know Flask/ Spring Boot so suggesting a particular approach is just not something I am comfortable with.  But search "Flink Speing Boot" on  this site. You will find lots of examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You want to read the data from Postgres (which I assume this question is about) You can use Flink JDBC connector, which will allow reading from various databases including the Postgres. You can find more info [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connect.html#jdbc-connector).

Comment: See also https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connectors/jdbc.html and https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connectors/formats/debezium.html.